# styles.css in runo theme is not loading

Tags: java, css, themes, vaadin

Currently im working on a vaadin project. i copied a working copy and started working on that. but when deployed the project and started the application on a browser (i checked in chrome and firefox too), the application did not start. it says that the styles.css in the runo(default template) folder is not loaded. but css in my custom theme is loaded. (*my earlier project was working fine*)

This information might be not sufficient. what i really want to know is what are the situations where styles.css doesn't load. or any other css doesn't load.

i cannot understand this behavior. please help me.

ps: the styles.css in problem is **not directly attached** to html file. it is imported through my custom css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered a similar issue. Try to clear Tomcat deployment directory (or whatever container you're using), cleaning your project and compiling the widgetset. This did the trick for me.